# Very first JavaScript

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I was following a tutorial and I cannot figure out where I went wrong.  Here is the Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imagecount = 1;
    var total = 5;

    function slide(x) {
        var Image = document.getElementsById('img');
        imagecount = imagecount + x;
        if (imagecount > total) {
            imagecount = 1;
        }
        if (imagecount < 1) {
            imagecount = total;
        }
        Image.src = "mock1" + imagecount + ".jpg";
    }
</script>
```

In the tutorial, `var Image` (the image changes colors but mine doesn't) same with document as well as the ('img').  I used the jaslint.com as suggested but it said it couldn't check because it expected a `/` instead got an `.`  Anyways any help appreciated.  I have never coded with Javascript and it's required for my assignment.

Comment: `getElementById` for a start. This would have come up as an error in the console log (F12 on Firefox).

Comment: Didn't work but thank you.  I have never done any JavaScript so I can stare right at the error and never see it.  My slideshow is not working at all.  Should I have to list each image although they didnt in the tutorial and it worked for them?

Comment: Have you got a link to the tutorial?

Comment: Here is the link to tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DcoiLed2iY

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var Image = document.getElementById('img');
```

instead of

```
var Image = document.getElementsById('img');
```